# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_preview'

Tags: django, django-forms

I am getting this error in Django 1.9

```
in PostForm
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_preview'
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    publish = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "image",
            "draft",
            "publish",
        ]
```

The dependencies installed in the virtual environment
**$ pip freeze**

```
certifi==2019.11.28
Django==1.9
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
django-filter==2.2.0
django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
django-pagedown==2.0.3
djangorestframework==3.11.0
Markdown==3.1.1
markdown2==2.3.1
olefile==0.46
Pillow==6.2.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`attrs`**-- (Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) parameter to pass the values to widget

```
widget=PagedownWidget(attrs={"show_preview":False})
```